Exception "System.IO.IOException" in Npgsql.dll
My project uses .NET Framework 4.0.
During the execution of a program for a certain operation, a message appears in the debugging console: An exception was raised: "System.IO.IOException" in Npgsql.dll .
There is such a message in the project logs:
System.IO.IOException: Data cannot be read from the transport connection: The remote host forcibly terminated the existing connection. 
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: The remote host forcibly terminated an existing connection
   в System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   ---  ---
   в System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   в System.IO.BufferedStream.ReadByte()
   в Npgsql.NpgsqlState.<ProcessBackendResponses_Ver_3>d__a.MoveNext() в C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlState.cs:line 672
   в Npgsql.NpgsqlState.IterateThroughAllResponses(IEnumerable`1 ienum) в C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlState.cs:line 326
   в Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectedState.Startup(NpgsqlConnector context) в C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnectedState.cs:line 53
   в Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open() в C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnector.cs:line 687
   в Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.GetPooledConnector(NpgsqlConnection Connection) в C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnectorPool.cs:line 447
   в Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.RequestPooledConnectorInternal(NpgsqlConnection Connection) в C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnectorPool.cs:line 255
   в Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.RequestPooledConnector(NpgsqlConnection Connection) в C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnectorPool.cs:line 197
   в Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectorPool.RequestConnector(NpgsqlConnection Connection) в C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnectorPool.cs:line 181
   в Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open() в C:\projects\Npgsql2\src\Npgsql\NpgsqlConnection.cs:line 536
   в ByndyuSoft.Gis.Web.Application.Infrastructure.Postgress.PostgressAbstract.Execute(NpgsqlCommand command, PostgresCommandTypes pgCommandType) в C:\Users\***\Documents\***\***\sources\Web.Application\Infrastructure\Postgress\PostgressAbstract.cs:line 33

And this is what my PostgressAbstract.cs looks like:
using NLog;
using Npgsql;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;

namespace Example
{
    public abstract class PostgressAbstract
    {
        private static Logger _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
        protected string Error { get; private set; }
        private object Result { get; set; }
        protected string ConnectName { private get; set; }

        protected PostgressAbstract(string connectName)
        {
            ConnectName = connectName;
        }

        protected object Execute(NpgsqlCommand command, PostgresCommandTypes pgCommandType)
        {            
            using (var thisConn = new NpgsqlConnection("Server=***;Port=***;Userid=***;Password=***;Protocol=***;SSL=***;Timeout=***;SslMode=***;Database=***;"))
            
            {                
                command.Connection = thisConn;
                if (pgCommandType == PostgresCommandTypes.Scale)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        thisConn.Open();
                        Result = command.ExecuteScalar();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Error = ex.ToString();
                        Result = null;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        thisConn.Close();
                    }
                }
                else if (pgCommandType == PostgresCommandTypes.Table)
                {                    
                    try
                    {
                        command.Connection.Open();

                        var da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(command);
                        var ds = new DataSet();
                        da.Fill(ds);
                        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
                        {
                            Result = ds.Tables[0];
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Error = ex.ToString();
                        _logger.Error(ex.ToString());
                        Result = null;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        thisConn.Close();
                    }
                }
                return Result;
            }
        }

        protected NpgsqlCommand CreateProcedureCommand(string nameFunction, IEnumerable<PostgresParameters> args)
        {
            var command = new NpgsqlCommand(nameFunction)
            {
                CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            };
            foreach (var par in args)
            {
                var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
                parameter.ParameterName = par.Name;
                parameter.DbType = par.Type;
                parameter.Value = par.Value;
                command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
            }
            return command;
        }
    }
}

Please help me find what is causing the exception

Given The remote host forcibly terminated an existing connection I would look at the Postgres log and the remote OS log for clues.

On a side note finally { thisConn.Close(); is unnecesary, the using does that for you.

@Charlieface you missed the NpgsqlCommand also implements IDisposable. OP I'd be looking for faulty hardware, run Disk Diagnostics, run your Router Diagnostics, do speed tests on your network, run the logging like Adrian said, eg: sudo tail -f /var/log/postgresql/postgresql.log

@JeremyThompson True, but that's passed in from the outside with an unknown lifecycle. Also AFAIK in practice it doesn't matter as long as you dispose the connection and reader.
